# Communication between two nested directives angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create a transclude directive using this HTML :

```
%h2 Widgets :
.row-fluid{ "ng-controller" => "ApplicationDashboardCtrl" }
  .span6
    %widget{ type: "chart", "ng-model" => "widget", "ng-repeat" => "widget in widgets","ng-transclude" => "" }
      .chart.bottom20
        {{ widget.title }}

      %data-source{ src: "/public/test.json"}
      %lines{ y: "value", x: "label" }

  .span6
```

The issue is, my two directives does not share the same scope instance. I created a plinkr to represent my issue :

[My issue using Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IGarrpals575FhOaIpln?p=preview)

I do not understand why my two directives does not share the same scope and why my "widget" directive does not catch the event "setupExtra". I know, I can use the $rootScope but I wanted to do without it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution, I have to use $emit instead of $broadcast

- $broadcast -- dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes,
- $emit -- dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.

Sorry for question, I keep it for other beginners :)